# unhashable type error for list inherited methods

Tags: python

```
from collections import UserList

# same with X(list):
class  X(UserList):
    def method(self):
        print("It runs")

xx = X()
xx.method()
print(hash(xx.method))
# same with list's own methods:
# hash(xx.append)  # also causes TypeError
```

Causes `TypeError: unhashable type: 'X'`  for Python < 3.8

Any ideas on how to make this work? (apart from upgrading interpreter)

Comment: Were you expecting something different? Lists aren't hashable, and you haven't implemented `__hash__` on `X`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I read the question as if there's no error in Python 3.8, which would really make me wonder. Why would lists be hashable in Python >= 3.8 if they weren't before?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it's unhashable in 3.8.5 on macOS.

Comment: It is hashable on TIO.run 3.8 pre-release https://tio.run/##PYy9CgIxEIT7PMVyNtnGxkYEH0CwFWxDLkcC@WN3xfPp44qnU818zEx/SWz1cOw0xkKtgG85By@pVYZUeiOBGwe6JhZjdsCuBHgmiXC3WRmejM@OGTT/espANYcFStD72XLIy0Y/6pSq2OkiQI/KExqzrnDWB1Sz3zZovrXoONo/RhzjDQ

Comment: It is also hashable in 3.8.2 on Windows (3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)])

Comment: @yan: well, you might have found some brittle stuff there. But, are you really trying to hash a method pointer? This sounds more like a XY-issue here. What underlying problem do you try to solve?

Comment: @ThomasWeller indeed thats a quite syntetic example. The original code passes method down to pyee to accumulate event-generated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround would be using lambda in init (any better options?).
Originally it had to collect data into list-like object from pyee library. And use list-inherited object's method as event callback.

Here's example to clarify how things supposed to work:

```
from pyee import BaseEventEmitter
ee = BaseEventEmitter()

class Data(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.store = lambda d: self.append(d)  # (!)workaround for py<3.8

storage = Data()
storage.store("some data") # test
print(hash(storage.store))  # This works in python 3.7

ee.on("received", storage.store)  # here we need it to be hashable
# ee.on("received", storage.append)  # and this fails in python 3.7
#... some even emitting code
```